# Using data outside of socket.on handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

This may be an easy answer, but im having trouble figuring it out. i want to use the data from these sockets, outside of the socket.on to compare them in order to do something. I've tried using global variable with no luck. I was thinking of grouping them, but the 'master' is an io.emit and the id is a socket.emit.

```
var playerId;
var masterId;

// Player socket.id
socket.on('id', function(data){
    console.log(data.id);
    var playerId = data.id;
});

// // Master socket.id
socket.on('master', function(data){
    console.log(data.master + ' is the master');
    var masterId = data.master;
});

if (playerId == masterId){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues how you're going about this.

Firstly is a scope issue. While there is nothing inherently incorrect with a global `playerId` and `masterId` when you use `var playerId` inside a function `playerId` becomes scoped to that function regardless of having the same name. For example:

```js
var playerId = 2;

function scoped(data) {
  var playerId = data.id;
  console.log(`${playerId} from the func. scoped`);
}

scoped({
  id: 4
});
console.log(`${playerId} from global scope`);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: initial !important;
}
```

The second issue is `id` and `master` are both events. Your program doesn't when when, or if, they'll be triggered. Not that big of a deal, until you try and compare them both after your event listeners with: `if ( playerId == masterId ) { .. }`. Since JS executes from top to bottom, and the if statement is in the global scope, it is executed immediately after the event listeners are registered. This means your if statement will always fail. As klanmiko mentioned you can write a separate function to do the checking for you.

Here is an example. The key differences are assigning `data.id` to the global version of `playerId`/`masterId` instead of declaring local versions of the variable and calling `checkId()` after each assignment.

```
var playerId = null;
var masterId = null;

socket.on('id', function(data) {
  playerId = data.id; // Assigns the global playerId = data.id;
  checkId();
});

socket.on('master', function(data) {
  masterId = data.id; // Assigns the global masterId = data.id;
  checkId();
});

function checkId() {
  if ( playerId == masterId ) {
    // Do something cool!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you need to do everything you would like to do in that socket.on, unless you pass the message to another loop running somewhere else, or you call another function from socket.on.

It seems that you are trying to synchronize the two events, where after you receive both you would like to compare if `playerId == masterId`

```
var playerId = null;
var masterId = null;

// Player socket.id
socket.on('id', function(data){
    console.log(data.id);
    var playerId = data.id;
    checkId();
});

// // Master socket.id
socket.on('master', function(data){
    console.log(data.master + ' is the master');
    var masterId = data.master;
    checkId();
});

function checkId() {
    if (playerId && masterId 
        && playerId == masterId) {
        // do something
    }
}
```